# C# functions in LinqToSql request

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have one problem. I need use c# function in linq to sql request.
for example:

```
      void request()
      {

            var db = new DataClasses1(connectionString);
            var result = 
                from a in db.Stats
                where Function(a.SourceName)
                select a;
        }
        bool Function(string sourceName)
        {

            return true;
        }
```

this is dont work because boolean Function(string sourceName) cant change to sql request. What i need to do for use c# functions in linq to sql?

Comment: What does this function do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `AsEnumerable` to your `linq` query:

```
  void request()
  {

        var db = new DataClasses1(connectionString);
        var result = 
            from a in db.Stats.AsEnumerable()
            where Function(a.SourceName)
            select a;
    }
    bool Function(string sourceName)
    {

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it if you can't convert your function to linq2sql statement but you can avoid of nonsql functions.

Finally there must be an **sql** to execute.

Just you can do is avoiding non sql statements shown below,

suppose that a is an string but you want it as integer,

```
var int_a = int.Parse(a);
var result = from a in db.Stats
             where a==int_a
             select a;
```

Answer (score 1):

your db doesn't know about the `Function`, so do it in two steps.

```
void request()
{
    var db = new DataClasses1(connectionString);
    var result = from a in db.Stats
                 select a;

    var finalResult = from b in a.AsEnumerable()
                      where Function(b.SourceName)
                      select b;
}
bool Function(string sourceName)
{
    return true;
}
```

see if it works